# Truly null-safe comparison

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a *truly* safe way of checking two nullable values are not equal in T-SQL that is shorter than this?

```
where
    A.MyField != B.MyField
or  (
        A.MyField is null
    and B.MyField is not null
)
or  (
        A.MyField is not null
    and B.MyField is null
)
```

Using `isnull()` isn't truly safe as it collapses `null` values into a 'real' value that could potentially exist in the data set, for eg:

```
where
    isnull(A.MyField, '') != isnull(B.MyField, '')
```

would incorrectly think that an empty string `''` and `null` are equal, which is not the desired result. You could come up with a "known" value that never occurs or is exceedingly unlikely to occur, but this seems like a band-aid fix.

Setting `ANSI_NULLS` off is also undesirable for several reasons (most particularly that the feature is being depreciated).

Is there functionality that will do a "true" null-safe check, or is the code above the best way?

Answer (score 2):

For versions from 2005+ [You can use](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html)

```
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT A.MyField
               EXCEPT
               SELECT B.MyField)
```

From SQL Server 2022 [you can use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
WHERE  A.MyField IS DISTINCT FROM B.MyField
```